# C++ template for global variable names

Tags: c++, templates, global-variables

I would like to have a function template in C++, that is able to use global variable names as template arguments. Something like this (the presented code is useless but I am interested into the concept):

```
int v1,v2;

template <int variable>
void run(int offset)
{
  variable = variable + offset;
}

main()
{
  v1 = v2 = 0;
  run<v1>(4);
  run<v2>(8);
}
```

If template is not the correct mechanism, what else would be better? My problem is, that now I have ten copies of the same (very long) function run() that differ only in the name of used global variables.

Comment: `template <int &variable>`? But why does it have to be a template argument rather than a normal function argument?

Comment: ... and why are the variables global?

Comment: you know about references? Whats wrong with `void run(int& variable, int offset) { variable += offset; }` ?

Comment: Thank you very much. The question is downvoted due to using basic C++ concepts totaly wrong. But I got the useful and working answer! About why is the question so wrong: probably this kind of misunderstanding can be expected from pure C programmer trying to jump on C++ :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular function arguments instead:

```
void run(int& variable, int offset);

int main()
{
  int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
  run(v1, 4);
  run(v2, 8);
}
```